# Pickle output is not readable

Tags: python, tkinter, pickle

Working on a notes program that saves notes, shows each note as tkinter window. Saves the notes in a pickled file, each pickled object is displayed as a label on a separate window.

```
    global notes
    load_color()
    f = open('m.data', 'rb')
    try:
        while True:
            try:
                notes = pickle.load(f)
            except EOFError:
                break
            root = Tk()
            root.title('Note')
            note_label = Label(root, text=notes, fg=color).pack(side=TOP)
            root.mainloop()
    except EOFError:
        pass
```

This is the function that shows each of the objects on a separate window. When displaying the notes, each of the notes are displayed like this:

`64832376note`

The color is displayed correctly.

Not sure why this is happening. It should have showed what I typed in as a note in the window. In case this doesn't explain enough, here is the full code so far: https://pastebin.com/6rpeFfED
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the statement `note = str(input("Take a note: "))` inside `note()` function will save the input note into **local** variable `note`.  Then you refer `note` inside `dump_notes()` function which actually refer to reference of `note()` function.

To fix the issue, most simply way is to modify `dump_notes()` function to accept argument, like `dump_notes(note)` and then update `dump_notes()` inside `note()` function to `dump_notes(note)`.